# Jupyter, which nbconvert template does what?

Tags: templates, jupyter, nbconvert

I'm currently triying to export a `.ipynb` with `nbconvert` using a special template. The final goal is to write a `.ipynb` and convert it to PDF, but erasing all Code-Input-Cells and havig the "normal" latex-style (font, dimensions of paper, and so on). I know that there are templates which provide exactly that (not sure if both at the same time), but I don't know which one of them to use.

So, does anybody know a template that provides that and can you link it to me? I've seen a lot of threads here on how to edit the templates, but to be honest I'm still not reallys sure how to do that. If there isn't a singel template that doest these two things (erase input-cells and font), do you know a site that provides an explanation in detail on how to edit these templates? (it would be nice if it isn't to "complicated" since I'm quite new to the concept of programming in general)

Thanks, 
Sito

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this blog post](http://blog.juliusschulz.de/blog/ultimate-ipython-notebook). There is a link on that page to a custom template that hides code cells and doesn't change the default font.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.